# Ember server side pagination

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm **not** trying to provide pagination within the view itself.

My API returns 500 records at a time and if there are more I'd like to automatically load them.

Although my solution right now does make the requests, I don't think it is the best way, but it does work.

```
App.StructureAdapter = App.ApplicationAdapter.extend({
  findHasMany: function(store, record, url) {
    // based on the normal `findHasMany` code
    var host = Em.get(this, 'host'),
        id   = Em.get(record, 'id'),
        type = record.constructor.typeKey;

    if (host && url.charAt(0) === '/' && url.charAt(1) !== '/') {
      url = host + url;
    }

    return this.findWithURL(this.urlPrefix(url, this.buildURL(type, id)), 1);
  },
  findWithURL: function(url, page) {
    var that = this;
    var completeUrl = url + "?page=" + page;
    var nextPage = page + 1;
    return this.ajax(completeUrl, 'GET').then(function(data) {
      Em.Logger.log("calling then");
      if (data.structures.length > 0){
        that.findWithURL(url, nextPage);
      }
      return data;
    });
  }
});
```

My questions are:

- Is there a better way to automatically get all of the pages for a given request?
- How do I properly make sure the relationships are built. My `Structure` object has parent/children relationships on it, but only the first page of results is actually being associated correctly.

#### Update

Here is what my json response looks like:

```
{
    "structures": [
        {
            "id": 6536,
            "name": "Building",
            "updated_at": "2013-05-21T07:14:54-06:00",
            "person_id": 6535,
            "notes": ""
        },
        ... 499 more objects ...
    ]
}
```

It works properly, it loads the first group just fine. And I can adjust it in the `extract`/`normalize` methods if I need to.

Here is my normalize method as it is right now:

```
App.StructureSerializer = App.ApplicationSerializer.extend({
  normalize: function(type, hash, prop) {
    // adds the properly link to get children
    hash.links = { "children": "structures" };

    // change structure_id to parent_id
    hash.parent_id = hash.structure_id;
    delete hash.structure_id;

    return this._super(type, hash, prop);
  },
});
```

Again, the links makes it automatically know where to look for the has many relationship.

Looking at it closer, though the paginated pages actually do get called, they are not loaded into Ember data at all. So maybe if they did get loaded then the relationships would build properly.

Comment: Can you post the json response your receiving from the server? What does your model look like?

Comment: Hello @NicholasJohn16, I just added the JSON response.

Comment: are you using [ember-data](https://github.com/emberjs/data)?

Comment: Yes I am using Ember data.

Comment: @RyanJM I've recently done some work with ancestry/self-join relationships too. I didn't find I had to use the normalize function; so I'm not sure if my example app would be helpful for you, or if you're using a better method that I didn't think of. Here's the link just in case: https://github.com/brandonjmckay/ember-ancestry-example

Comment: Thanks @BrandonJMcKay. I don't see where you have a limit of information coming back in the query. It looks like you are just grabbing the kids relationship normally. Am I missing something? In my case, the API wasn't returning everything and I had to do subsequent calls to get it all.

Comment: It wasn't for the pagination, but for the associations. The example app I referred to doesn't tackle that part. Thought it might still be helpful though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the best idea I have, I dunno how well it'd work and you might need to play around with it a bit.

In your `StructureRoute`, go ahead and return the model as normal, so:

```
App.StructureRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model:function() {
        return this.store.find('structure');
    }
});
```

That'll fetch your first 500 objects and begin the route transition.

Then in your `StructureController`, fetch the other models using query parameters like this:

```
App.StructureController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    init:function() {
        this.loadNextPage(2);
        this._super();  // this may not be necessary still, but the docs call for it
    },
    loadNextPage: function(page) {
        var self = this;
        var promise = this.store.find('structure',{page:page});

        promise.then(function(structures) {
            if(structures.get('length') < 500) { 
                self.loadNextPage(page + 1);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

So when the `StructureController` initiates, it'll call the recursive function `loadNextPage`.  This will keep running until it hits a page contains less then 500 models.  Hopefully, that'll be the last page.  By [providing the second parameter to find](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/finding-records/#toc_querying-for-records), Ember should trigger a request to `/structure?page=2`.  Inversely, you could do all of this in the route, if you don't mind the slow load time.

If at all possible, I would suggest modifying your API to add some pagination meta data to your request.  Then you can use that metadata to control when to stop the recursive function.  You can see [how to handle metadata here](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/handling-metadata/).

Finally, I'm not sure if that's a typo in your json, but you may need to [override your pluralization](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_pluralization-customization).

Anywho, hope that helps and I didn't overly simply the problem!

Comment: Nicholas, thanks for the answer. Not sure why I didn't see it sooner. I'll have to try it out, but I think that will be a lot better than what I tried. :)

Comment: Looks like this has the same issue I have with mine. I'm not doing an Array controller, I'm doing an ObjectController and then looping over the children. The children relationship doesn't get updated when doing this find. https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1864

Comment: If you're representing multiple models, you should be using an ArrayController.  Why are you using an ObjectController?

Comment: I'm presenting a tree structure. Parent (ObjectController) which loops over the children (which each get their own ObjectController). I need an ObjectController so I can provide functionality based on the particular structure the user is working with.

Comment: Thanks for the help Nicholas. This got me to a cleaner solution. I'm able to manually add the objects for now until Ember Data gets fixed.

Comment: Glad to help! I see what you mean in your example.  That's very odd.  It must be a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't like this solution, but this does **work**. Please post if you have a much cleaner way of doing this.

### Step 1: Load the Data into Ember Data

Since the data wasn't being loaded into Ember Data for the other pages I had to manually load it. I did that by adjusting the `findWithURL` function I created above.

```
findWithURL: function(url, page) {
  var that = this;
  var completeUrl = url + "?page=" + page;
  var nextPage = page + 1;
  var store = EditUserApp.__container__.lookup('store:main');
  return this.ajax(completeUrl, 'GET').then(function(data) {
    if (data.structures.length > 0){
      that.findWithURL(url, nextPage);
    }
    store.pushPayload('structure', data);
    return data;
  });
},
```

I feel like there should be a cleaner way to do this, but it works.

### Step 2: Rebuild the relationships

For some reason it didn't seem to be rebuilding the child/parent relationships. To take care of that I had to use the `didLoad` callback inside of the `Structure` model.

```
didLoad: function() {
  var parent = this.get('parent');
  if (parent) {
    var that = this;
    parent.get('children').then(function(children) {
      children.addObject(that);
    });
  }
},
```

Any suggestions for how to improve this solution are welcome. Ideally I feel like there should be a better Ember way to handle this whole scenario.